# Reshaping arrays so that they can fit machine learning model

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, scikit-learn

Im making image classifier but I have a problem with reshaping data.
My dataset (for now) is very small, it contains 19 images, size 75x75.

When I processed my pictures, i got two arrays, for features and results:

Shape for features: `(19, 75, 75)`

Shape for results: `(19,)`

When I pass that arrays to my model, I get this error:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=0)
model = clf.fit(features, results)

ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

I do not know how to reshape this data, can you please help me?
I want to add my image so that i can classify it:

```
my_image = r'C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\image_classifier\Prediction\predikcija.jpg'
img_array = cv2.imread(my_image, 0)
img_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (img_size,img_size))

my_prediction = model.predict(img_array)
print(my_prediction)
```

I get this error:

```
   ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 6400 and input n_features is 80
```

Comment: maybe you should reshape 2D items with sizes `75x75` to 1D items with sizes `5625` (75*75)

Comment: Can yo u tell  me how to do that?

Comment: `array.reshape((19, 75*75))`

Comment: Ok but what should I do If I  want to input my image for classification, please see the  code. I have updated it

Comment: second error show `Model n_features is 6400` which means that it expects rows with 6400 values (it is `80*80`) and `input n_features is 80` means you put rows with `80` values. I guess that `img_size` is `80`. I would expect it has to be `model.predict(img_array.reshape(80*80))` - so it convert 2D array `80x80` to 1D list with `6400` values.